# How to create a column based on the value of the other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
    type_x  Range  myValname
0     g1   0.48        600
1     g2   0.30        600
2     g3   0.62        890
3     g4   0.75        890
```

I would like to get the following dataframe

```
    type_x  Range  myValname newCol
0     g1   0.48        600    c1
1     g2   0.30        600    c1
2     g3   0.62        890    c2
3     g4   0.75        890    c2
```

The significance of `c1` and `c2` are that if the myValname is same for a `type_x` value then both the value can be treated as same value. I want generalized code.

My thinking is to convert it into dictionary and map some values, but unable to get the outcome.

```
 df3['newCol'] = df3.groupby('myValname').rank()
```

Comment: Why can't you just use myValname? newCol seems to be nothing more than a renamed version of that column... If you require categorical type you could use `df['myValname'].astype(pd.CategoricalDtype())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
 df["newCol"] = df.groupby("myValname").ngroup().add(1).astype(str).radd("c")
```

- for each unique "myValname", take the group order of it (0, 1, ...)
- since it's 0-based, add(1) to get 1, 2, ... instead
- then stringify it to add from right "c"

to get

```py
>>> df
  type_x  Range  myValname newCol
0     g1   0.48        600     c1
1     g2   0.30        600     c1
2     g3   0.62        890     c2
3     g4   0.75        890     c2
```

where after `.ngroup()`, this was here:

```py
>>> df.groupby("myValname").ngroup()

0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
dtype: int64
```

---

alternative with pd.factorize:

```py
df["newCol"] = pd.Series(pd.factorize(df["myValname"])[0] + 1, dtype="str").radd("c")
```

where now pd.factorize assigns 0, 1, ... to each unique value in "myValname", and after that the same modifications follow as before.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.cat.codes` attribute when you convert the dataFrame column into a `categorical` dtype:

```py
df['newCol'] = df['myValname'].astype('category').cat.codes.apply(lambda x: 'c' + str(x))
```

In the `.apply` method, it gets the categoric value and puts a ***c*** before it (to your liking).

Answer (score -1):

You can add/append a new column to the DataFrame based on the values of another column using `df. assign()` , `df. apply()` , `np. where()` functions and return a new Dataframe after adding a new column.

Comment: not my downvote but answer needs improvement; too generic as it stands.